# iOS Enterprise developer Account: apns certificate for push notification

Tags: ios, apns, certificate, mobile-device-management, enterprise

I have used the iOS development account for creating apns ssl certificate for sending push notification to iOS device for development purpose.I can get the device token using objective c sample code in iOS device.Then I can use that device token to send push notification for that specific iOS device.

Now I am going to implement MDM and for MDM iOS Enterprise account is required.There are some questions, which I want to confirm if someone has already done.

1.So I want to know can I use iOS Enterprise account for creating "apns ssl certificate" for development purpose?

2.Can I get device token for iOS device using the same objective C sample code, so that I can send the push notification to that specific iOS device for testing purpose.

Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent avinash1236213! Questions about programming and the Apple Developer Programs are off topic per the [FAQ](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq). Try to post your question at [stackoverfow](http://www.stackoverflow.com) instead.